# Converting xml file into json dump python

Tags: python, xml, json

Hi i want to parse xml file into json dump. Already tried this:

```
for i in cNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("person"):
        self.userName = i.getElementsByTagName("login")[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        self.userPassword = i.getElementsByTagName("password")[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        self.userNick = i.getElementsByTagName("nick")[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
```

But i want to get titles and values in format title:value, using for loop.

```
<user>
<person>
    <nick>Gamer</nick>
    <login>1</login>
    <password>tajne</password>
</person>
<properties>
    <fullHp>100</fullHp>
    <currentHp>25</currentHp>
    <fullMana>200</fullMana>
    <currentMana>124</currentMana>
    <premiumAcc>1</premiumAcc>
</properties>
```

This is my xml format.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel (with "minidom" it would not be fun anyway), use [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict):

```
import xmltodict

data = """
<user>
    <person>
        <nick>Gamer</nick>
        <login>1</login>
        <password>tajne</password>
    </person>
    <properties>
        <fullHp>100</fullHp>
        <currentHp>25</currentHp>
        <fullMana>200</fullMana>
        <currentMana>124</currentMana>
        <premiumAcc>1</premiumAcc>
    </properties>
</user>"""

print xmltodict.parse(data)
```